# Testing Z in Assembly - Microchip pic16f84a

Tags: assembly, pic

I have the following code:

```
            MOVLW 5
            MOVF V1
            MOVLW 4
            MOVF V2

            MOVF V1,0
            SUBLW V2,1
```

I am new to the assembly code, I need to test Z to see if the subtraction is 0, any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this (e.g.) :

```
BTFSS STATUS,Z
GOTO not_zero_code
GOTO zero_code
```

If `BTFSS STATUS,Z` doesn't work, you can try `BTFSS STATUS,2` (I'm not sure if the `Z` is recognized by the assembler)

And you can get the datasheet of the pic at this address : http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/Devices.aspx?product=PIC16F84A

It contains all informations about registers and assembler intructions of the uC

Hope it will help you.